# Printing Ancestors of a node in Binary Tree

Tags: java, algorithm, tree, binary-tree

I need to print the ancestors of a node in binary tree. e.g Node 7 has ancestors as 1,3 . I have written the below code but output is coming as 7. Can you suggest the issues in this code?

```
    1
   / \
  2   3
 / \ / \
4  5 6  7 

 public static String findAncestor(BinaryTreeNode root , int number,  boolean matched) {

    if (root != null) {

        int rootData = root.getData();

        BinaryTreeNode left = root.getLeft();
        BinaryTreeNode right = root.getRight();

        if (left != null && right != null) {
            return findAncestor (root.getLeft(), number, matched ) + findAncestor (root.getRight(), number, matched);               
        }

        if (left != null) {
            return findAncestor (root.getLeft(), number, matched ) ;        
        }

        if (right != null) {
            return findAncestor (root.getRight(), number, matched ) ;
        }

        if (rootData == number) {
            matched = true;
            return String.valueOf(rootData);        
        }   
        if (matched) {
            return String.valueOf(rootData);        
        }   
    }   
    return "";  
}
```

Comment: define "not working" - what behavior are you getting? What are you expecting?

Comment: @Amit, I am getting 7 as ancestor

Answer (score 3):

```
public boolean findAncestorPath(List<Integer> ancestors, BinaryTreeNode node, int number) {
    if (node == null)
        return false;

    int data = node.getData();
    if (data == number)
        return true;

    if (findAncestorPath(ancestors, node.getLeft(), number)) {
        ancestors.add(data);
        return true;
    }

    if (findAncestorPath(ancestors, node.getRight(), number)) {
        ancestors.add(data);
        return true;
    }

    return false;
}
```

Then you'd call this as (you should also probably wrap it in a function):

```
List<Integer>() ancestors = new ArrayList<Integer>();
boolean found = findAncestorPath(ancestors, root, number);
```

Note that the `ancestor` list would be reversed.

Comment: @Isoliveira, thanku. This solution gives everything except root node.

Comment: @Manish - Can't see why... I've tested it and it returns the root node, also (unless it contains the value which you're looking for but in that case the return value is `true`). Have you tested it?

Comment: Note that if the tree is an ordered binary tree, there's a better/faster traversal algorithm available as it's not necessary to traverse all nodes.

Comment: @Isoliveira Why  can't we apply the same logic as printing from root to leaf path?

Comment: I'm afraid I don't understand what you mean, @AKS. Could you rephrase that?

Answer (score 0):

Here is the Java implementation

```
public static List<Integer> ancestors(BinaryTreeNode<Integer> root, Integer target) {
    List<Integer> result = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    findAncestors(root, target, result);
    return result;
}

private static boolean findAncestors(BinaryTreeNode<Integer> node, Integer target, List<Integer> result) {
    if (node == null) {
        return false;
    }
    if (node.getData() == target) {
        return true;
    }
    if (findAncestors(node.getLeft(), target, result) || findAncestors(node.getRight(), target, result)) {
        result.add(node.getData());
        return true;
    }

    return false;
}
```

Here is the unit test case

```
@Test
public void allAncestors() {
    BinaryTreeNode<Integer> root = buildTree();
    List<Integer> ancestors = BinaryTreeUtil.ancestors(root, 6);
    assertThat(ancestors.toArray(new Integer[0]), equalTo(new Integer[]{5,2,1}));
}
```

Answer (score -1):

This piece of code work fine for giving all the ancestors a particular node , node is root node and value is the value of the node for which we have to find all the ancestor.

```
static boolean flag=false;
  static void AnchersterOf(AnchesterNode node,int value) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
      if(node==null)
          return ;

      if(node.value==value){

          flag=true;
          return;
      }

     if(flag==false){
      AnchersterOf(node.left,value);
      if(flag==true){
            AnchersterOf(node,value);

      } if(flag==true)
      System.out.println(node.value);
    AnchersterOf(node.right,value);
    if(flag==true)
          System.out.println(node.value);
     }





    }
```

Comment: That may be the case, but this (1) doesn't recognize issues in the OP's code, and (2) is totally divorced from the OP's code, relying on different names and classes.